# What if the instrumental variable is endogenous in first stage

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variable, endogeneity

Suppose $y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x+u,E(xu)\not=0,E(u)=0$.
$z$ satisfies $E(zu)=0$ (exogenous) and $Cov(x,u)\not=0$ (relevance).
In first stage, we do $x=\pi_0+\pi_1z+v$ and get $\pi_1=\frac{S.Cov(x,v)}{Var(z)}.$
In reduced form, we do $y=\alpha_0+\alpha_1z+e$ and get $\alpha_1=\frac{S.Cov(z,y)}{Var(z)}.$
I find it's hard to show $\pi_1, \alpha_1$ are consistent since $Cov(z,e)$ and $Cov(z,v)$ are different from $Cov(z,u)$. Especially, what if $z$ is exogenous in first stage, i.e. $Cov(z,v)\not=0$?
I know we can show consistency of $\beta_1^{IV}$ by plim operator, but can we say it's allowed to have $Cov(z,e)$ and $Cov(z,v)$ to be nonzero? That is, the divided two steps are only used for calculation with no econometric meaning.